# Can't get PHP FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL to work

Tags: php, email, filter

so this is my first post ever so please excuse me for the quality.

I've been struggling to find out how to make this code work

```
<?php
$email = isset($_POST["email"]);
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
?>
//html
<?php } ?>
```

It always get the "incorrect email format" message even if it's a correct email address.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: hard code the email and check weather it's working or not `<?php var_dump(filter_var('s7sunder@gmail.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)); ?>`

Comment: Also check your input parameters by using this comments `<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>` some times you may misspelled the input parameter name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
$email = isset($_POST["email"]);
```

isset() returns TRUE or FALSE, and you are storing that boolean result in the $email variable, which obviously isn't an email. You probably meant something like:

```
$email = $_POST["email"] ?? '<value if not set>'; //php7 only
```

or...

```
$email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : '<value if not set>';
```

Comment: your second proposition worked perfectly for me ! thanks alot. I'm just starting php and I didn't know it was a boolean value I didn't read properly --" anyway thanks again

Comment: No worries, if my answer solved your problem, click the green check mark under the two voting buttons to mark it as such.